how to classify based on a column values from database in django
i wanted to classify some data from database and show it in a table
this is how get the data
<tbody>
   <tr class="">
   {% for c in cluster %}
      <td>{% if c.hasil_klasifikasi == 'Banyak Terjangkit' %}{{ c.nama_penyakit }}{% endif %}</td>
      <td>{% if c.hasil_klasifikasi == 'Kurang Terjangkit' %}{{ c.nama_penyakit }}{% endif %}</td>                                
   </tr>            
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>

and this is the views.py
cluster = tb_hasil_cluster.objects.all()
context = {'chart':chart,'cluster':cluster}
return render(request, 'hasil-cluster.html', context)


here is the database if you wonder
but the results dont looks right
result on the table
any help would be very much appreciated, thanks
i was trying to classify the data in the table without blank cell like that
i want to get the data like this here

You should put the <tr> (the table-row), inside the loop:
<tbody>
    {% for c in cluster %}
    <tr class=""> <!-- 🖘 inside loop -->
        <td>{% if c.hasil_klasifikasi == 'Banyak Terjangkit' %}{{ c.nama_penyakit }}{% endif %}</td>
        <td>{% if c.hasil_klasifikasi == 'Kurang Terjangkit' %}{{ c.nama_penyakit }}{% endif %}</td>                                
    </tr>            
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>

it still showing the same output, nothing change at all
